# Why is my Xcode simulator still darkened after adding text into my text field?

Tags: ios, xcode

I added the Rounded Text Field and the whole screen became darkened in the iphone simulator that Xcode runs. I thought I just needed to input text and then it will un-darken the screen but it just stays like this: [(Darkened Simulator, next to how it should appear)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjwjn.png)

I was wondering if this is just a bug in the simulator or if my app will appear like this at the end of development?

Comment: Share line of code on text field typing function.

Comment: is it a third party library rounded text field, or standard `UITextField` that you just styled?

Comment: standard UI text field